# django category and subcategory selection on admin page

Tags: django

I'm having three tables: *Category*, *Subcategory*, *Products*. The *Subcategory* table has a category id field as a foreign key.

While inserting new product, there are two select boxes:

1. First select is for Category (its working)
2. Second is for Subcategory

I need to fetch the data from subcategory table. Which should be relevant to the 1st select ?

Thank you.

Comment: Use django-treebeard library for this purpose. It have great feature and API related parent-child concept

Comment: @shyam http://www.programfaqs.com/faq/django-admin-how-to-populate-select-options-depending-on-another-select/